# gcc toolchain for Ralink RT3350 cpu model : MIPS 24Kc V4.12

Tags: gcc, mips, linux-toolchain

I am searching for gcc toolchain for **Ralink RT3350 cpu model : MIPS 24Kc V4.12** for last 3-4 days. i need to wite program for this same cpu model. so if any one knows share the gcc toolchain link and the way to use this toolchain. As far as my pc environment concern **i am using Ubuntu 11.10**

Answer (score 2):

Did you check code-sourcery ?

Check out their lite version for MIPS architecture.
(Sourcery G++ Lite 4.2-85 for MIPS GNU/Linux)

https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/subscription3130?lite=MIPS

Good luck !!

Comment: I also recommend the CodeSourcery toolchain for MIPS GNU/Linux, and that is the right link, though the original poster might be confused because the names have changed.  Here's the background:  In 2010, CodeSourcery was acquired by Mentor Graphics and Sourcery G++ was renamed Sourcery CodeBench.  New Lite and commercial editions are still released by the same engineering team periodically.

Comment: @Icarus3: should it be exactly 4.2-85 for MIPS 24Kc V4.12? I mean is there any strict relation between Sourcery G++ version and MIPS CPU type? (I see there a lot of fresher versions)

Comment: @ArtM Not really, you could use latest version. You would be passing architecture type to gcc/g++ using -march( just guessing, check the documentation )